# Algorithm Maths Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Hi I'm stuck on this maths question don't really know how to about it. I've tried simultaneous equation to solve for a and b with no success. Hope you can help.

---

A program looks up a specific entry in a sorted list of size $n$.  Suppose that the program is implemented on Computer $A$, using a linear search algorithm, and on Computer B, using a binary search algorithm.  Tests are run to compare the algorithms (the run time is measured in nanoseconds):

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}n~\text{list size}&A~\text{run time}&B~\text{run time}\\
\hline
10&70~ns&150,000~ns\\
\hline
100&340~ns&200,000~ns\\
\hline
1,000&3,040~ns&250,000~ns\\
\hline
1,000,000&3,000,040~ns&400,000~ns\\
\hline
100,000,000&300,000,040~ns&500,000~ns\end{array}$$

(i) The program run on computer $A$ has a linear growth rate of the form: $f(n)=an+b$.  Find $a$ and $b$.

(ii) The program run on computer $B$ has a logarithmic growth rate of the form: $g(n)=c\ln(n)+k$.  Find $c$ and $k$.

(iii) Use L'Hopital's rule to find the limit:
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{g(n)}{f(n)}$$

and hence determine which algorithm is more efficient for large values of $n$.

Comment: Check that your image matches your question.  The variables $a$ and $b$ do not appear anywhere in your image.

Comment: Sorry wrong image now I updated it

Comment: It will benefit you greatly in the long run to learn how to type your questions instead of simply posting images of the question.  Not only will it give you practice in typing which will be highly important as you progress through academia and towards a career, but it will also help future users who have similar question as you to find your question via the search function.  Visit [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a primer on how to type using MathJax and $\LaTeX$ on this site.

Comment: I've TeXeD your image for you.  Look to see how I typed it.  As for your actual question, you say you tried to find $a$ and $b$ via simultaneous equations.  That is a good plan and should have worked.  What equations did you use and why did it cause you trouble?  (Note, you could just as easily have spotted what the pattern is by inspection without using a system of equations realizing that $70=30+40$)

Comment: If you're struggling with calculating the logarithmic function, realising that $100=10^2$ could be helpful if you know your logarithm identities, namely $\ln(x^a)=a\ln(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part (i), as you say, you can find $a$ and $b$ by solving a system of equations:

We are given the following system for $A$:

$\begin{cases} 70 = 10a + b\\ 340 = 100a + b\\ 3040 = 1000a+b\\ \vdots\end{cases}$

We are told that it is linear, so we know that the same $a$ and $b$ will work for all of the equations, so we only really need to use two of them.  Let us approach via the method of substitution:

$\begin{array}{lr} 70=10a+b & \text{subtract}~ 10a~\text{from each side}\\
70-10a=b & \text{so this way of writing}~b~\text{can be used elsewhere}\\
340=100a+b & \text{from the second equation}\\
340 = 100a+(70-10a) & \text{by substituting our expression for}~b\\
270 = 90a&\text{by subtracting 70 from each side and simplifying}\\
3 = a&\text{by dividing both sides by 90}\\
70=10a+b&\text{by going back to the first equation}\\
70=10\cdot 3 + b & \text{by plugging in the found value of}~a\\
40=b&\text{by subtracting 30 from each side}
\end{array}$

So, we find the answer to part (i) to be $f(n)=3n+40$.  Do so similarly for part (ii).  Apply L'Hopital's rule and find the limit to find the answer in (iii).

---

The system for $B$ is:

$\begin{cases} 150000 = c\ln(10) + k\\
200000 = c\ln(100)+k\\
250000 = c\ln(1000)+k\\
400000 = c\ln(1000000)+k\\
\vdots\end{cases}$

which simplifies to:

$\begin{cases} 150000 = c\ln(10)+k\\
200000 = 2c\ln(10)+k\\
250000=3c\ln(10)+k\\
400000 = 6c\ln(10)+k\\
\vdots\end{cases}$

using the property of logarithms that $\ln(a^b) = b\ln(a)$

Comment: For part 2 do you sub in 10 to In and i got 2.3 and got 21,739 for c and 100,00 for k. Is that right? Is In the natural log? because that what I used to  get 2.3

Comment: @Tom you should keep things as exact as possible.  $\ln(10)$ is an irrational number which is *approximately equal* to $2.302585$ but not *exactly equal*.  Keep it as $\ln(10)$.  No harm done.  For $\ln(100)$ note that $\ln(100)=\ln(10^2)=2\ln(10)$ and that $\ln(1000)=\ln(10^3)=3\ln(10)$ etc...  Don't bother trying to change $\ln(10)$ into an approximate number, let your final answer have to do with $\ln(10)$.  Things will simplify nicely enough that it won't matter.  Just treat it as an irreducible like you would a variable like $x$.

Comment: I got 25,000 for c and 92,436 for k. I don't think that's right. Is it?

Comment: @Tom I will say it again, *keep answers exact*.  If your answer doesn't have "$\ln(10)$" somewhere in it, it couldn't possibly have been right.  Secondly, it will definitely be $c$ which is the irrational number, not $k$.  I'll reiterate my hint from before, don't let the logarithm scare you.  Don't think about solving for $c$... think about solving for $(c\ln(10))$.  Can you solve the system $\begin{cases}150000=d+k\\ 200000=2d+k\\ 250000=3d+k\\\vdots\end{cases}$?

Comment: i got 100,000 for k and 21714 for c

Comment: @Tom I'll say it a *third time*, **keep answers exact**.  Apart from that, yes you finally have it.  Instead of referring to $c$ as $21714$, refer to it as $\frac{50000}{\ln(10)}$ which is *approximately but not equal* to $21714$.  Only use equals signs for **equalities**, not for approximations.

Comment: ok thanks. Is this the right idea for part 3? 50000/In(10)ln(n) + 100,000/ 3n + 40

Comment: @Tom apart from the poor typesetting, yes you seem to know where to go next.  Parenthesis are your friends when typing mathematics without using proper $\LaTeX$.  Without them, the whole meaning might change.  The way you wrote it, it looks like $\frac{50000}{\ln(10)}\ln(n) + \frac{100000}{3n}+40$ which is different from what you want which is $\frac{\frac{50000}{\ln(10)}\ln(n)+100000}{3n+40}$.  Now use the properties of limits and [L'Hopital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) to reach the conclusion.

Comment: I don't know how to go about it as they In(n) is confusing me

Comment: @Tom If you "plug in $\infty$" does that give you any useful information?  No, because it is indeterminate of the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.  So, we use L'Hopitals.  What is the derivative of the top equation?  What is the derivative of the bottom equation?  It helps to have the common functions' derivatives and anti-derivatives memorized, but [here is a sheet](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Common_Derivatives_Integrals.pdf) that has most of the common ones that you will run into.

Comment: I got 3/10 is that right?